# Why the firebase data doesn't appear in the recycler view?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

the firebase data doesn't appear in the recycler view

i have some realtimeDb in Google firebase 
i try to read it in the recyclerView but nothing appears ,

logcat shows null and here is my code:

1-**Here is HomeFragment(Main) Code**

```java
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    Unbinder unbinder;
    @BindView(R.id.recycler_popular)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
       unbinder= ButterKnife.bind(this,root);
       init();
       homeViewModel.getPopularList().observe(this, new Observer<List<PopularCategoryModel>>() {
           @Override
           public void onChanged(List<PopularCategoryModel> PopularCategoryModel) {
               //create adapter
               MyPopularCategoriesAdapter adapter = new MyPopularCategoriesAdapter(HomeFragment.this.getContext(), PopularCategoryModel);
               recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
           }
       });
        return root;
    }

    private void init() {
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    }
}
```

**2-Here is HomeViewModel Code**

```java
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel implements IPopularCallbackListener {

    private static final String TAG = "HomeViewModel";
    private MutableLiveData<List<PopularCategoryModel>> popularList;
    private MutableLiveData<String> messageError;
    private IPopularCallbackListener popularCallbackListener;

    public HomeViewModel() {
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<PopularCategoryModel>> getPopularList() {
        if (popularList== null){
            popularList=new MutableLiveData<>();
            messageError=new MutableLiveData<>();
            loadPopularList();
        }
        return popularList;
    }

    private void loadPopularList() {
        final List<PopularCategoryModel> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference popularRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.POPULAR_CATEGORY_REF);
        popularRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tempList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot itemSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    PopularCategoryModel model=itemSnapShot.getValue(PopularCategoryModel.class);
                    tempList.add(model);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange:Adel2020"+tempList.size()+popularRef);

                }
                //popularCallbackListener.onPopularLoadSuccess(tempList);
                Log.e(TAG, "Data received:" + tempList.size());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                popularCallbackListener.onPopularLoadFailed(databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public MutableLiveData<String> getMessageError() {
        return messageError;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPopularLoadSuccess(List<PopularCategoryModel> popularCategoryModels) {
        popularList.setValue(popularCategoryModels);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPopularLoadFailed(String message) {
        messageError.setValue(message);
    }
}
```

**3- This is the Adapter**

```java
public class MyPopularCategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyPopularCategoriesAdapter.PopViewHolder> {
    private List<PopularCategoryModel> listPopularCategoryModel ;
    Context context;

    public MyPopularCategoriesAdapter( Context context,List<PopularCategoryModel> listPopularCategoryModel) {
        this.listPopularCategoryModel = listPopularCategoryModel;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PopViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new PopViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate
                (R.layout.layout_popular_categories_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PopViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(context).load(listPopularCategoryModel.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.popCategoryImage);
        holder.popCategoryName.setText(listPopularCategoryModel.get(position).getName());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listPopularCategoryModel.size();
    }

    public class PopViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Unbinder unbinder;
        @BindView(R.id.pop_category_name)
        TextView popCategoryName;
        @BindView(R.id.pop_category_image)
        CircleImageView popCategoryImage;
        public PopViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            unbinder= ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

**4-This is Model**

```java
public class PopularCategoryModel {
    private String menu_id,food_id,name,image;

    public PopularCategoryModel() {
    }

    public PopularCategoryModel(String menu_id, String food_id, String name, String image) {
        this.menu_id = menu_id;
        this.food_id = food_id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public PopularCategoryModel(String name, String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }
```

+SetterGetter

**5-Here is the Data**
[image]

Comment: Did you debug your code and check the firebase data is coming or not. If data is not coming, then the problem in fetching data, not in the recycler view

Comment: I use the same data in confirmation and work well, but here when i retreve the parent it successfully retrived but childs return null.

Comment: Use same field name as your database field name like use Image instead of image